# Isomorphism on Homology induced by Inclusion of CW-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, surfaces, cw-complexes

I want to prove the following and I do not know how.

Let $X$ be a CW-complex of dimension $n-1$ and let $Y$ denote the space obtained from $X$ by attaching a finite number of $n$-cells. Then the inclusion $j:X \to Y$ induces isomorphisms:
$$ H_i(X) \to H_i(Y)$$
for all $i \leq n-2$.

Comment: Have you looked at the long exact sequence for the pair $(Y,X)$? This will reduce your claim to a statement about relative homology groups, on which you can then use excision.

Comment: Do you mean the exact sequence induced from $$0 \to C_n(X) \to C_n(Y) \to C_n(Y,X) \to 0 $$ in homology? And which version of excision?

Comment: Yup, that one is usually known simply as «the long exact sequence for the pair $(Y,X)$».

Comment: And do you mean use excision like $H_i(Y,X) \cong H_i(Y/X)$? Because I am stuck there, since I do not know how to calculate that group.

Comment: If you know that excision, then you can use it :-) It shows that the relative homology of the pair $(Y,X)$ is the same as that of a wedge of $n$-spheres.

Comment: Otherwise, there is the "other" excision, which shows that $H_i(Z,A)\cong H_i(Z-U,A-U)$ for appropriate subsets $U$ of $A$. How to do this in your case is a bit longish to explain — it is done in detail in the book by Greenberg and Harper, for example.